# Silverlight Prism MEF Module Configuration

Tags: silverlight, prism, mef

I am just getting my head around Prism, MEF and modularisation.

It seems that you can only configure Silverlight modules via code, however, with WPF you can configure via a config file or via a directory ie without the need to hard code the values giving true pluggability.

Is this really the case? If so why? Surely the whole point is to avoid re-compiling? The separation of concerns can be easily achieved without using MEF or Prism?

Or am I missing something obvious?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You could define a xaml file e.g. modulecatalog.xaml in which you define the modules...

So to add/remove modules would mean to edit the xaml file.